# Libgdx error clickListener

Tags: java, libgdx, clicklistener

I have 5 button and a want each button can't print number 1,2,3,4,5. but each button only print "5". Is there any wrong with my code? Or its bug on libgdx? I use libgdx v1.2.0

```
for (Integer i = 1; i <=5 ; i++){
     tabeldalam=new Table(skin);
     tabeldalam.row();
     tabeldalam.add(new Label("GAmbar :", skin)).height(100).width(100);
     tabeldalam.row();
     tabeldalam.add(new Label("Harga",skin)).height(30).width(100);
     tabeldalam.row();

     TextButton nextbutton = new TextButton("Beli",skin);
     nextbutton.setWidth(100);
     nextbutton.setHeight(20);
     nextbutton.addListener(new ClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
             beli(i);
         }
     });
     tabeldalam.add(nextbutton).height(20).width(100);

     tabelLuar= new Table(skin);
     tabelLuar.add(tabeldalam).width(100).height(150);
 }

private void beli(Integer i){
    text2.setText(i.toString());
}
```

Comment: What is `j` in the invocation `beli(j);` ? You haven't included the source code thta defines `j`

Comment: sorry wrong typing I mean "i"

Comment: Is this Java? Then you should include the [tag:java] tag.

Answer (score 0):

try this simple example:

...// **Change in your Code *addListener* for this:**

```
nextbutton.addListener(new ClickListenerOverflow(i) {

         @Override
         public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
             beli(n);
         }
     });
```

...//

**Add this code inside of your Class:**

```
private class ClickListenerOverflow extends ClickListener{

    int n;

    public ClickListenerOverflow(int n){
        this.n = n;
    }

}
```

when you click call `beli (i)`, `i` then its value is 5, it is the latter who won the `for`.

Answer (score 0):

Use int instead of Integer for your for loop. All of your click listeners are referencing the same instance of Integer because it is an object and not a primitive.

For code non-ambiguity I would copy the variable to a final int variable and use that for the click listener so it is absolutely clear that a separate int is used for each.

```
final int index = i;
...
//use index in the ClickListener instead of i
```